# AWS IoT POST request from .NET CF 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, compact-framework, aws-iot

I have the following problem - I'm trying to perform the POST request from device with `.NET CF 3.5` to AWS IoT to publish message to topic. It works good for doing the same to Azure IoT Hub, and from app on `.NET 4.5`. But when I trying to make request to AWS I always get exception `the connection has timed out`.
This is how I doing the request:

```
    public static HttpWebResponse InvokeHttpRequest(Uri endpointUri,
                                         string httpMethod,
                                         IDictionary<string, string> headers,
                                         string requestBody)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = ConstructWebRequest(endpointUri, httpMethod, headers);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requestBody))
            {
                var buffer = new byte[requestBody.Length]; // arbitrary buffer size                        
                var requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
                using (var inputStream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(requestBody)))
                {
                    var bytesRead = 0;
                    while ((bytesRead = inputStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        requestStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                }
                requestStream.Flush();
                requestStream.Close();
            }

            return CheckResponse(request);
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            using (var response = ex.Response as HttpWebResponse)
            {
                if (response != null)
                {
                    var errorMsg = ReadResponseBody(response);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n-- HTTP call failed with exception '{0}', status code '{1}'", errorMsg, response.StatusCode);
                }
                return null;
            }
        }
    }
```

The urls, headers, and everything else are ok, because it works in .NET 4.5. Is there a known limitation of CF which can cause such problem?

**Note**
I was needed to add

```
  <system.net>
<settings>
  <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>
</settings>
```

in .NET 4.5 Client because otherwise I got an exception `The server committed a protocol violation. Section=ResponseStatusLine`, so maybe this info can help. Thanks!

**UPD**
Here is the `ConstructWebRequest` and `CheckResponse` code:

```
public static HttpWebRequest ConstructWebRequest(Uri endpointUri,
    string httpMethod,
    IDictionary<string, string> headers)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpointUri);
    request.Method = httpMethod;

    foreach (var header in headers.Keys)
    {
        // not all headers can be set via the dictionary
        if (header.Equals("host", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            continue;
        else if (header.Equals("content-length", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            request.ContentLength = long.Parse(headers[header]);
        else if (header.Equals("content-type", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
            request.ContentType = headers[header];
        else
            request.Headers.Add(header, headers[header]);
    }
    return request;
}

public static void CheckResponse(HttpWebRequest request)
{
    // Get the response and read any body into a string, then display.
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\n-- HTTP call succeeded");
            var responseBody = ReadResponseBody(response);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(responseBody))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\n-- Response body:");
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody);                        
            }
        }
        else
            Console.WriteLine("\n-- HTTP call failed, status code: {0}", response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

Comment: What line did you get an exception on?  What was the full stack dump of the exception?  Also, show the code for `CheckResponse` and `ConstructWebRequest`.

Comment: @tcarvin added code. The source is the `GetRequesStream()`

Comment: Are you sure you are setting ContentLength to the correct value?  Additionally, I think ContnetLength will auto-populate based upon the size if the RequestStream anyway, so you might want to try skipping that all together.

Comment: @tcarvin I will, thanks. But the same code works well when I'm sending the request to Azure IoT Hub also using HTTPS. My thoughts Is that maybe something wrong with AWS endpoints, but thats weird because the very same code works well when compiled and run under .NET CF 3.9, .NET 3.5+

Comment: @tcarvin Also, if interested you can refer to my this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45734620/https-request-the-operation-timedout-exception-net-cf-3-5?rq=1, there I posted Wireshark trace

Comment: Where did you ever get the idea that AWS supports .NET CF?  AFAIA There is no CF support at AWS.  There is no mention of it in any of their doc's.